# Philosophy: is erb the right choice for a dynamic web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I joined a large ongoing Ruby on Rails project (my first RoR) about six months ago. The website is very application-like, it is not just a bunch of static webpages. It seems to me that erb is **not** well suited to building dynamic, application like websites, erb seems better suited for  mostly static webpages with maybe some forms. JavaScript is the only real choice for dynamic websites. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Sorry my friend, but this isn't the correct place to ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

No.  That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I'm more interested in what experienced developers have to say, not that you said much. Why not? Explanation? ERB requires more back and forth (between client and server) and more bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry for my curtness but as you can tell from the downvotes your question was fairly poor.  You ask about ERB but it seems as though you are asking if ruby is the right choice for a dynamic web app.  Erb is just a way to embed ruby in your views so to compare it to JS is not correct out of the box.  Further, "JavaScript is the only real choice for dynamic websites" is not a statement that you can make without supporting facts.  The fact that you seemingly don't understand the difference between ruby and erb makes me think you don't have the supporting facts.

Comment: More likely I struck a nerve. Javascript has the ability to manipulate data and UI on the client side, which ERB (like JSP and PHP) obviously cannot. I shouldn't need to explain that. There are plenty of examples (e.g. mega.nz) that use JS and are awesome. Any examples of good dynamic ERB sites?